# How do I move/copy a symlink to a different folder as a symlink under Solaris?

Tags: solaris, symlink, cp

It is an odd behaviour seen only on Solaris that when I try to copy a symbolic link with the "`cp -R -P`" command to some other folder with a different name, it copies the entire directory/file it's pointing to.

For example:

```
link -> dir

cp -R -P link folder/new_link
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/138587/how-to-copy-symbolic-links

Answer (score 5):

I believe the "-d" argument is what you need.

As per the [cp man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp):

```
-d     same as --no-dereference --preserve=link
```

Example:

```
cp -d -R -P link folder/new_link
```

I was using "cp -d" and that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

[The cp man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/cp-1.html) seems to say that you want to use an '-H' to preserve symlinks within the source directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [cpio](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7m6q/index.html) (with the -p (pass) option) or the old tar in a pipe trick.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider copying via tar, like tar -cf - srcdir|(cd somedir;tar -xf -)